# Using npm commands to start NodeJS project with arguments

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create two separate npm commands to start my NodeJS project locally on the dev machine and in production mode. I want to be able to pass arguments to the machine separately to serve the right dependencies - which could be a CDN in production OR my local machine.

Here's what I am looking to have in package.json

```
"run": "node ./server/app.js", /* for running locally*/

"start": "node ./server/app.js", /* for running in production*/
```

If I try to call npm run - it creates this error:

```
npm ERR! npm run-script [<pkg>] <command>
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I also want to be able to send commandline argumentswhich would contain a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing it right.

To call custom scripts, you have to run

```
npm run-script run
```

Your package.json should have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server/app.js",
    "run": "node ./server/app.js"
}
```

See: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-run-script.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash script to run any (even nested) module directly with arguments. Don't forget to change `~/Develop/node_modules` to your local path.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Usage: npmrun module [args]
    exit
fi
data=~/bin/npmrun.data
if [ -f $data ]; then source $data
else declare -A where
fi
cd ~/Develop/node_modules
if [ -z ${where[$1]} ]; then
    path=$(find -path '*/bin/'$1)
    if [ -z $path ]; then
        echo "Module \"$1\" not founded!"
        exit
    else
        where[$1]=$path;
        declare -p where > $data
    fi
fi
${where[$1]} ${@:2}
```